# $\ell^0$ norm algorithm?

Tags: vectors, algorithms, normed-spaces

it is mentioned somewhere that $\ell^0$ is not a norm, but it is used to find the **number of zeros in a vector**, but **what algorithm is used to do so**? In $\ell^p$ the common equation is $||x||_p=(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\ldots+|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, $\ell^0$ is the number of *nonzero* entries in a vector. If you know what $x$ is, can't you just go through all the entries and count the number of nonzero ones? This is can be done in $O(n)$ time.